# как в строку типа String с префиксом r вставить переменную?

Tags: dart

В строке типа String есть префикс r. Такая строка выводит все как есть.

```
void main() {
 String str = r'abc\n123';
 print(str);
}
```

> abc\n123

Как в строку типа String с префиксом r вставить переменную?

```
void main() {
 String text = 'Yes';
 String str = r'abc\n123$text';
 print(str);
}
```

> abc\n123$text

Знак доллара выводится, потому-что строка с префиксом r выводит все как есть. Есть ли такой способ вставки переменной, что бы знак доллара не выводился, может его как-то экранировать?

Answer (score -1):

Смотри если я не путаю нужно писать с пробелом типо вот так

```
String str = r'abc\n123 $text';
```

**надеюсь помог:)**

P.s я новичек если я что то не так пишу, прошу написать мне это в ответ

Comment: Уважаемый tenter34, Вы у себя Ваш ответ тестировали?